# How to query for count?

Tags: django, django-orm

I've got a query,

```
Bid.objects.filter(shipment=shipment, status=BidStatuses.ACCEPTED, user=request.user, items__count=0).exists()
```

The part that doesn't work is `items__count=0`. Bids have a many-to-many relationship with items. I need to check if this bid has 0 items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/

see the doc upon, read the sample,you will find the answer

Comment: `Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors')).filter(num_authors__gt=1)`. Didn't think to annotate and then filter in the same query for some reason.... using annotate everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For the record (there is already an accepted answer with a link to Django aggregation docs), what OP needs is:

```
Bid.objects.annotate(item_num=models.Count('items')).filter(shipment=shipment, status=BidStatuses.ACCEPTED, user=request.user, item_num=0).exists()
```

Comment: I put 2 and 2 together, but thanks for going the extra mile and spelling it out anyway :)